# Validate Engine moves using Perft and divide

Tags: engines, computer-chess, performance, perft

I'm developing a small Engine in Java, before trying something more elaborate in C/C++. Right now I'm running some perft tests (the 'perf_talkchess' file), but as expected it has some bugs. Consider this position:

#### FEN r3k2r/1b4bq/8/8/8/8/7B/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1

```
[fen "r3k2r/1b4bq/8/8/8/8/7B/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

I wrote the following perft method:

```
    public long perft(int depth){

        List<Move> moves = board.getAllMoves(board.state.currentPlayer);
        int n_moves = moves.size();
        long totalNodes = 0L;

        if (depth == 1){            
            return n_moves;
        }

        for (Move mv : moves){                      
            board.makeMove(mv);
            totalNodes += perft(depth - 1);         
            board.undoMove(mv);
        }
        return totalNodes;
    }
```

My perft (4) gives 1184480, it should be 1274206. In order to debug the position, I wrote this:

```
   public void divide(){

        List<Move> moves = board.getAllMoves(board.state.currentPlayer);

        for (Move m : moves){
            board.makeMove(m);
            //ignore the 0 arg
            Perft p = new Perft(board.toFEN(), depth, 0);
            p.run();
            board.undoMove(m);
            System.out.println(m + ":" + p.result);
            total += p.result;
        }
        System.out.println("Moves: " + moves.size());
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
```

When I run

```
Divide d = new Divide("r3k2r/1b4bq/8/8/8/8/7B/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1", 3);
d.divide();
```

I got `Moves: 26` `Total: 1276215` and a very long output. I have 2 questions:

a) How do I properly write/use a divide algorithm?

b) How do I handle the castle state inside the make/unmake methods? What are the general traps to avoid regarding castle rights? I guess I'm screwing up the undo move code. What I do now is the following:

At makeMove I backup the current state before applying the move

```
makeMove(move)
  prevState.x = currentState.x
  prevState.y = currentState.y
  ...
  if (move.isFoo)
      change currentState accordingly
  ...
```

At undoMove I just restore the currentState and undo the board:

```
undoMove(move)
  currentState.x = prevState.x
  currentState.y = prevState.y
  ...
  if (move.isFoo)
      undo board state accordingly
  ...
```

Maybe there's some flaw with the reasoning above, I can post the code if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Who wrote the `Perft` class?

Comment: I did, it's very straightforward. I've rewritten the make/unmake moves, now this position is solved, but I'm having trouble with a much more complex one. I'll edit the post, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. How would you handle multiple recursion in your undoMove? You aren't saving your current board to something like a stack or a hash table? When your function reaches depth==3, your current board would have been corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**

I wouldn't code up a new divide function because if you have a bug in your code, your new function will also be buggy.

Why don't you use Stockfish? Do you know you can run perft on Stockfish?

In Stockfish, run the following:

```
position fen r3k2r/1b4bq/8/8/8/8/7B/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1
d
perft 3
```

You should get the following:

```
Position: 1/1
h2g1: 1160
h2g3: 1320
h2f4: 1444
....

===========================
Total time (ms) : 2
Nodes searched  : 27826
Nodes/second    : 13913000
```

Now you just need to add a std::cout to the perft function in `search.cpp`.

Find the function `uint64_t Search::perft(Position& pos, Depth depth) {` in `search.cpp`, then use it to print out all the positions in your perft search.

You can then compare your perft moves with Stockfish with the following Unix commands:

```
sort MyPerftMoves > MySortedPerftMoves
sort SFPerftMoves > SFSortedPerftMoves
diff MySortedPerftMoves SFSortedPerftMoves
```

**Q2**

You should use Zobrist hashing if you haven't. This is the standard technique for board representation in chess. In Stockfish, the code below does the trick for castling:

```
// Update castling rights if needed
if (st->castlingRights && (castlingRightsMask[from] | castlingRightsMask[to]))
{
    int cr = castlingRightsMask[from] | castlingRightsMask[to];
    k ^= Zobrist::castling[st->castlingRights & cr];
    st->castlingRights &= ~cr;
}
```

Your move representation should be able to tell you what castling move it is, and what castling rights (queen side? king side?) it has. This is implemented in Stockfish as `castlingRightsMask[from] | castlingRightsMask[to]`. Once you know your rights, you can just add it to your Zobrist key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found the problem reading this http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?topic_view=threads&p=234006&t=25096. I'm certainly will be back here when I start to code an advanced engine, thanks!

Comment: Stockfish uses now `go perft 3` in stead.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer my own question, the bug I had is better explained here:

http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?topic_view=threads&p=234034&t=25096

My make/undo/perft code are correct, the problem was that the board state (castle rights and ep square) were being destroyed in the recursion. For example:

```
1  e2-e4 a7-a6 
2  e4-e5 d7-d5 // ep square created at d6 
3  c2-c3 // ep square destroyed        
4 ..c7-c6
```

Now when you undo the move c2-c3 the ep square at d6 is gone. The same happens for castle states. Some solutions are given in the link, I did the following:

```
BoardState makeMove(move)

    //currentState is a ivar
    freezeState = currentState.clone

    //update currentState, board, ep square and castle rights
    if (move.castle_ks && currentState.player == WHITE)
        currentState.white_castle_ks = false
        currentState.white_castle_qs = false
    else if (mv.pawnJump)
       currentState.epSquare = ...
    ...

    return freezeState

void undoMove(move, prevState)
    // undo state
    currentState.white_castle_ks = prevState.white_castle_ks
    currentState.white_castle_qs = prevState.white_castle_qs
    ...

   //undo board
```

Now it works

```
public long perft(int depth){

        List<Move> moves = board.getAllMoves(board.state.currentPlayer);
        int n_moves = moves.size();
        long totalNodes = 0L;

        if (depth == 1)                 
            return n_moves;     

        for (Move mv : moves){                  
            BoardState undo = board.makeMove(mv);               
            totalNodes += perft(depth - 1);         
            board.undoMove(mv, undo);
        }
        return totalNodes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding B, the classic trap is not undoing all the changes one makes to the board in the unmake move.  One thing that I do when debugging is to make a copy of the board before making & unmaking moves, and testing equality later. (I override the copy constructor & equality operator for my Board class)

```
#if VALIDATEBOARD
    Board boardControl(_board);
#endif

_board.PopulateMoveList(moveList, moveCount, oppositionAttackTable);

for (int moveIndex = 0; moveIndex < moveCount; moveIndex++) {

        _board.DoMove(moves[moveIndex]);
        // DO SOMETHING WITH MOVE
        _board.UndoMove();

#if VALIDATEBOARD
        assert(_board == boardControl);
#endif
    }
```